# How to check if a Facebook dev user is part of an app's Admin, Developer or Tester role?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I've looked a lot into the Facebook Graph API and I couldn't find a document that explains how to check if a user is part of a Facebook App's Administrators, Developers or Testers role.

Is there a way to get that information through REST API/Facebook Graph using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, from the application control panel

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that I want to check for that information possibly through a REST API like using Facebook Graph API in JavaScript. Checking who's dev, tester or admin on the app's control panel is a breeze, but I need a way to check that through code.

Comment: Well, then use the API – I linked the relevant docs section for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will fetch a list of all the roles associated with the user:

```
SELECT application_id, role FROM developer WHERE developer_id = me()
```

If you application access token, then you can fetch a list of all developers and their roles as such:

```
SELECT developer_id, role FROM developer WHERE application_id = 0
```

More information can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/developer/.